# NTM - Network Traffic Monitor GUI

Tags: networking, monitoring, system-monitor, network-monitoring

I installed NTM and I have a few queries:

1. I tried to launch it both from cl or using the icon but I do not know if it is running !
2. Whenever I tried to launch it from terminal I am getting "Vector smash protection is enabled."
3. I keep receiving a message from OS (in the upper right corner) saying:
   " NTM - Time slot An additional slot was used" ?!
4. I would like to have&use the GUI because I am not that savvy with cl.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Click on terminal

Type in:

```
gnome-system-monitor
```

Then on the icon bar, right click on it and lock it to the bar.

You'll be GUI from then on.

[image]